# Sharepoint web service for file modification date

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint

Is there a Sharepoint web service that offers file info (including last modification date) on given file path ?

I know [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) but I want to request only for a single file and not for entire folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Query element with the Where clause in your GetListItems to get the info for just one item/file: [Query Element (List)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093.aspx)

Your XML will be something like:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='The_x0020_Field_x0020_You_x0020_Want_x0020_To_x0020_Use_x0020_To_x0020_Filter' /><Value Type='Text'>My Criteria</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```